# Why is Xcode showing error in initialization of method with argument?

Tags: swift, initialization

This error is showing, unable to get through it.

[image]

```
let contact : Contact = Contact(dict: demodictionary)
```

Following is the Class with init method I want to initialize contact object like in Objective-C:

```
// Contact Class
@implementation Contact

-(instancetype)initWithDict:(NSDictionary * ) dictionary {
    self = [super init];
    [self populateDataFromDictonary:dictionary];
    return self;

}
```

Comment: Doesn't Xcode's suggested fix solve the problem?

Comment: Xcode is showing an error because there is something wrong with your code... What error is it?

Comment: @penatheboss The error message was in the question but OP had deleted it. I've edited it in again.

Answer (score 2):

The bridged type for `NSDictionary` in *swift* :

```
[NSObject: AnyObject]
```

So the objective-c bridging method expects as `[NSObject: AnyObject]`

[From Doc:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html)

> When you bridge from an NSDictionary object with parameterized types
>   to a Swift dictionary, the resulting dictionary is of type
>   [ObjectType]. If an NSDictionary object does not specify parameterized
>   types, it is bridged to a Swift dictionary of type [NSObject:
>   AnyObject].

Answer (score -2):

```
    let contact : Contact = Contact.init(dict: demodictionary as [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

solves it.

Comment: You don't need the `.init` part, just use the normal syntax for initialization: `Contact(dict: demodictionary as [NSObject : AnyObject])`. Also, Xcode is showing you the solution, and Kumar has also already answered, so I'm not sure why you have posted that?